# [ElasticSearch]: Get all indices containing a specific value

Tags: elasticsearch

Following is the use case:

I am trying to list all indices in elasticsearch that contain a particular value.
For illustration purposes let us consider following to be the index template:

```
    {
  "order": 0,
  "template": "sample-*",
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "300",
    "index.number_of_replicas": "1",
    "index.number_of_shards": "10"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "digital": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "website": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "store": false,
          "type": "string",
          "doc_values": true
        },
        "iab_codes": {
          "store": false,
          "type": "long",
          "doc_values": true
        },
        "audiences": {
          "store": false,
          "type": "long",
          "doc_values": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {

  }
}
```

The `audiences` field in this template is a sequence of long eg. `[1,2,3]`. I create one index per day based on this template. How can I get the list of all the indices that contain a specific value in the `audiences` array field.

Something like list all the indices where audience array contains the value `3`.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a search query similar to

```
http://localhost:9200/sample-*/_search?q=audiences:3&pretty
```

and using the Java API, you can try getting the value of `hits.hits._index`

Or rather use filter_path :

`http://localhost:9200/sample*/_search?q=audiences:3&filter_path=hits.hits._index&pretty`

[Result will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQyxr.png)